# Live UML Editors

Tags: uml

Are there any UML tools that show live updates?
I'm trying to have a design session online where all participates in their turn can change the design and add their own thoughts.
I prefer desktop solutions but online tools can work as well.
How would you suggest to do this?

EDIT:
I'm talking about [something like this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtumldesigner/) but maintained.
A co-developer told me it doesn't really work well and it's very buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com) includes live discussion forums that are linked to the model, so one can discuss individual parts of your UML model. In addition, although I haven't done this myself, I know model files are based on a database, and can be updated simultaneously by multiple users. This is either a Jet database for the lower-level versions, up to an Enterprise-level database for the Corporate editions.

I'm pretty sure it updates pretty much immediately, though i can't testify that I've seen it happen: I've always been the lone modeler!

Comment: The link is broken. Also this is an open sourced project and I'm not going to get everyone in it to buy this.

Comment: The link is now fixed. Talk to the company. If your OSS project is neat enough, they may throw you a discount. It looks like you'd need the Professional edition for shared models.